query or formular to count this week and comparison days a week before
I have a sheet. I the first Column there is the date of every day in the year (ddd dd.mm.yyyy).
In the second Column there are the values.
I want to compare the sum of the current week, starting on Mondays till today, with the sum of the comparison days of the week before.
Example File
don´t know if query or formular is better in this case.
one of some failed tries
=query(A:B; "SELECT sum(B) WHERE A >= date '"&TEXT(WEEKDAY(TODAY();...

but then it ends.

sheet is private

new link should work now

for this week:
=SUM(IFNA(FILTER(B:B; WEEKNUM(A:A; 2)=WEEKNUM(TODAY(); 2); A:A<=TODAY())))

or:
=SUM(IFNA(FILTER(B:B; WEEKNUM(A:A; 2)=WEEKNUM(TODAY(); 2))))


for previous:
=SUM(IFNA(FILTER(B:B; WEEKNUM(A:A; 2)=WEEKNUM(TODAY(); 2)-1; A:A<TODAY()-6)))



or if you prefer ugly SUMIFS:
=INDEX(SUMIFS(B:B; WEEKNUM(A:A; 2); WEEKNUM(TODAY(); 2); A:A; "<="&TODAY()))

and:
=INDEX(SUMIFS(B:B; WEEKNUM(A:A; 2); WEEKNUM(TODAY(); 2)-1; A:A; "<"&TODAY()-6))

